# Error after adding an image to a Word doc in java2word

Tags: android, java2word

I am using the [java2word](//github.com/leonardoanalista/java2word) library to create a Word document in Android. It's working fine, but when I try to add an image to the document, it crashes with the below error. Why am I getting this error, and how do I fix it?

Here's my code:

```
private void saveFile() {       

    IDocument myDoc = new Document2004();
    myDoc.encoding(Encoding.UTF_8);
    myDoc.setPageOrientationLandscape();

    myDoc.addEle(Image.from_WEB_URL(
            "http://www.google.com/images/logos/ps_logo2.png"));
    myDoc.addEle(Heading1.with("Document Create Test : " + firstName + " " +
            lastName +".").create();
    myDoc.addEle(BreakLine.times(1).create()); //two break lines    

    String myWord = myDoc.getContent(); 

    File fileObj = new File("file:///android_asset/mydocument.doc");

    PrintWriter writer = null;
    try {
        writer = new PrintWriter(fileObj );
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    writer.println(myDoc.getContent());
    writer.close();         
}
```

When I execute the above code, I get the following error:

```
  05-12 23:46:20.693: E/AndroidRuntime(7093): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  05-12 23:46:20.693: E/AndroidRuntime(7093): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:   javax.imageio.ImageIO
  05-12 23:46:20.693: E/AndroidRuntime(7093):   at word.w2004.elements.Image.<init>(Image.java:40)
  05-12 23:46:20.693: E/AndroidRuntime(7093):   at  word.w2004.elements.Image.from_WEB_URL(Image.java:162)
  05-12 23:46:20.693: E/AndroidRuntime(7093):   at com.paysheet.SignatureAcitivity.saveFile(MyTestActivity.java:164)
  05-12 23:46:20.693: E/AndroidRuntime(7093):   at com.paysheet.SignatureAcitivity.save(MyTestActivity.java:99)
  05-12 23:46:20.693: E/AndroidRuntime(7093):   at com.paysheet.SignatureAcitivity$1.onClick(MyTestActivity.java:77)
  05-12 23:46:20.693: E/AndroidRuntime(7093):   at  android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3517)
  05-12 23:46:20.693: E/AndroidRuntime(7093):   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14155)
  05-12 23:46:20.693: E/AndroidRuntime(7093):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have the xstream library to be able to handle images with java2word. You can get the library from here: https://code.google.com/p/java2word/downloads/detail?name=xstream-1.3.1.jar&can=2&q=